# Vue prevent router-link from submitting when quick view button is click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a quick view button inside a router-link and when I click it, the router-link keep submitting. I do not want the router-link to submit to the quick view button event. Instead I just want to show the quick view popup window right there. Something similar to this link
[Unconditional](https://www.unconditional.uk.com). When you hover over the image a quick view button show and when you click it, the quick view window popup. And when you just click product image instead of the quick view button, it take you to a different page. That is what I want to achieve. How can I achieve this? If there is a different way to it, I would love to see that too.

```
<router-link tag="li" :to="{name: 'Product', params: {product}}"
             v-on:click.native="getItem">
  <div class="container">
    <img :src="product.image" alt="" class="card-img">
    <div class="overlay">
      <button @click="active = true">Quick View</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</router-link>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will resove the issue:

```
<button @click.prevent="active = true">Quick View</button>
```

.prevent modifier will prevent the button to do what is meant to do by deafult

Or you can do it by adding 'type="button"' to your button (it won't trigger the submit)

```
<button type="button" @click="active = true">Quick View</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking to do is to prevent the default action on the button click.

You can read about how to do this here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

`<button v-click.prevent="onClick"></button>`

Have a quick read of the docs as you also might want to use `.stop`